# incorrect argument - vector

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to port the code from flipbook component in Flex to Air 1.5.1, it gave this error
1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 0.

```
delta = new Vector(new Point(x,_pointOfOriginalGrab.y),new Point(x+10,_pointOfOriginalGrab.y+1));
```

How do I make it work in Air?

Answer (score 2):

From the Flex documentation, it looks like `Vector` constructor accepts a `length` for it's first argument and `fixed` for its second argument.  You can rewrite you code as this:

```
delta = new Vector();
delta.push(new Point(x,_pointOfOriginalGrab.y));
delta.push(new Point(x+10,_pointOfOriginalGrab.y+1));
```

Here's the documentation page:

[Vector Documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Vector.html#Vector%28%29)

Comment: Oh, it worked by disabled the "Strict type checking" option in Flex builder.